# Unable to Create a Workflow in SP administration

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow

Goal:
Use a one of OOB:s workflow that is included in the SharePoint 2013

Problem:
I retrieve a error message that says

> "The form cannot be rendered. This may be due to a misconfiguration of
>   the Microsoft SharePoint Server State Service. For more information,
>   contact your server administrator. "

and I used a solution based on the source code

```
$serviceApp = New-SPStateServiceApplication -Name "State Service"
New-SPStateServiceDatabase -Name "StateServiceDatabase"
-ServiceApplication $serviceApp
New-SPStateServiceApplicationProxy -Name "State Service"
-ServiceApplication $serviceApp -DefaultProxyGroup
```

(http://www.jeremytaylor.net/2010/06/02/sharepoint-2010-the-form-cannot-be-rendered-this-may-be-due-to-a-misconfiguration-of-the-microsoft-sharepoint-server-state-service-for-more-information-contact-your-server-administrator/)

Unfortunately, the source code for the PowerShell does not work and I
still have the problem with error message above.

Information:
-I'm using SharePoint 2013

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The State Service Application Proxy should not have the same name as the State Service Application. Try your powershell again with something like the following for your last line:

```
New-SPStateServiceApplicationProxy -Name "State Service Proxy" -ServiceApplication $serviceApp -DefaultProxyGroup
```

Comment: Unfortunately, same problem occur. Please look at the new picture above.

Comment: A couple of things about that new screenshot: 1) was the snapin added (i.e. Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell") 2) looks like you have some erroneous carriage returns at the ends of lines 2&4

Answer (score 1):

Better you choose the sharepoint central administration as an admin 
and navigate to configuration wizard and select the state and servces option and launch the wizard. this may help you